# I'm getting 404 error on every page in django

Tags: python, django

I'm developing my first app in Django and facing some issues. The server runs smoothly and I can operate the admin panel without any issues.

**However, all of the app pages including the default homepage show a "404 not found" error.**

1. I have created a templates directory in project root
2. updated this line in settings.py for templates,

   ```
   'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
   ```
3. View for the app

   ```
   from django.shortcuts import render
   from .models import *

   # Create your views here.
   def customers(request):
       customers = Customer.objects.all()
       return render(request, "customers.html", {'customers': customers})
   ```
4. urls for the app

   ```
   from django.urls import path from . import views

   urlpatterns = [path('customers',views.customers, name='customers')]
   ```
5. urls for the project

   ```
   from django.contrib import admin from django.urls import path, include from django.conf import settings from django.conf.urls.static import static

   urlpatterns = [
       path('trips/',include('trips.urls')),
       path('customers/',include('customers.urls')),
       path('drivers/',include('drivers.urls')),
       path('vehicles/',include('vehicles.urls')),
       path('admin/', admin.site.urls), ]

   urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
   ```

Help is appreciated

Comment: In Markdown you can not combine a numbered list with a code block. I recommend to drow the numbers.

Comment: Thanks. I will keep that in mind

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any problem with your case, you should be able to load `http://localhost:8000/customers/customers`. Maybe double customers was not you intention, then remove one of them (one in main `urls.py` one in app's).

Also when Django debug mode is active and you get a 404 because of URL mismatch, it shows you a list of URLs you have. To see it navigate to a non existing URL like `http://localhost:8000/aaa`. Then if you see `customers/` there try `http://localhost:8000/customers/`. Go step by step to find the problem.

Comment: Oh. Thanks a ton. That worked. The double customers was unintentional and I din;t think of that